# Static block variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, static-variables

Is it possible to have a static variable of a "block type"?

I have a class that only does stuff in static methods. Upon execution of those methods i'm calling `statusChangedBlock`. Just for that i create a shared instance of the class, and use its single block property. I wonder if it's possible to have a static block variable; so i wouldn't have to create a instance with a single property, just for notifying that my status changed.

I know there is an option of NSNotification, but i don't like using it, with some rare exceptions.

...this question somehow sounds stupid, i can't tell why. I hope someone points that out.

Comment: you can declare it static, but not create it static. it is what function for

Comment: @BryanChen i can't figure out how to declare it static; also not sure what do you mean by "function for". Can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to declare a static variable of block type

```
typedef ReturnType (^MyBlockType)(ArgumentType, ArgumentType2);
static MyBlockType myblock;
static MyBlockType myblock2;
```

or

```
static ReturnType (^myblock)(ArgumentType, ArgumentType2);
```

Comment: `static MyBlockType myAssignedBlock = ^ReturnType(ArgumentType arg1,ArgumentType2 arg2){...do something...};` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A block type variable is actually a pointer, similar to an object. You can have a static block variable, but you must assign its value at runtime, perhaps using a `dispatch_once` block.

Comment: Thanks! it would realy help if you provided some simplest example